# How to deploy Tableau Dashboard Extensions (web app) locally with Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, tableau-api

Tableau dashboards extensions (https://www.tableau.com/developer/extensions) are essentially html/css/js web apps that are used for within Tableau. I have created one, and now I have been asked to "dockerize" the app locally, so that it can then be run on either an AWS EC2 instance or GCP server. I understand the benefits of Docker, and that I need to create a Dockerfile for this, however I am struggling with the implementation of this. I have installed Docker on my computer. Here is some output from my terminal (on Mac):

```
> docker --version
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
> npm --version
6.13.4
> node --version
v12.15.0
```

I have a directory for my Tableau extension, with the following files included:

- my_web_app.html (the main JS is included as a script in the html file)
- d3.v5.min.js (JS with d3 library, loaded into html file)
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- my_web_app.trex (the .trex file is the entrypoint into the app for Tableau (i believe))
- tableau.extensions.1.latest.js (JS with the tableau extensions API, loaded into html file)

There is no backend to this app, and in order to run my web app locally, I currently just run `npm start` from my command line, from within this directory.

My question is, how can I "dockerize" this web app, so that I can run the app locally with `docker run ...` in terminal? In particular, should I be searching online for how to deploy a Node.js app with docker (for which there are many examples), or an npm app with Docker, etc.? I don't run `node index.js` to use this app at all, and so I don't think I need a node.js Dockerfile, although I'm not exactly sure what is needed for this.

### Edit 1

Since there's no backend to my app, I don't (at least, I don't think) have an `index.js` or `server.js` file in my directory, which I think is causing some confusion for me with how to do this.

### Edit 2

Here's my current efforts. I have the following file named `Dockerfile`, that looks like:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 8081
```

I ran `docker build` (I am already cd'd into the directory with the app) and received the following output:

```
> docker build . -t shot_charts_docker_container
Sending build context to Docker daemon  119.2MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:12
12: Pulling from library/node
c0c53f743a40: Pull complete 
66997431d390: Pull complete 
0ea865e2909f: Pull complete 
584bf23912b7: Pull complete 
3c4c73959f29: Pull complete 
63e05266fc4b: Pull complete 
b00869e1130e: Pull complete 
45b49819ba5a: Pull complete 
87465fce1a7f: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:facc1cbde6e5aa3255092b1a1417451953c80bd31ab5a4403f8bcd90b90a8407
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:12
 ---> d834cbcf2402
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in a30398234870
Removing intermediate container a30398234870
 ---> da3b6160bd05
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json /app
 ---> 7459e2d070b9
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 0f7eeae1dfde
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.

> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /app/node_modules/ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)

added 698 packages from 479 contributors and audited 7147 packages in 19.527s

15 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing intermediate container 0f7eeae1dfde
 ---> 8a2667e42b0a
Step 5/7 : COPY . /app
 ---> debe78f1501a
Step 6/7 : CMD npm start
 ---> Running in 58b466b8dde8
Removing intermediate container 58b466b8dde8
 ---> 7b26023a3b1b
Step 7/7 : EXPOSE 8081
 ---> Running in 6c5d2c9d8012
Removing intermediate container 6c5d2c9d8012
 ---> fd2ef4b32da5
Successfully built fd2ef4b32da5
Successfully tagged shot_charts_docker_container:latest
```

I removed some warnings from the above output in order to shorten it for this post, as I didn't think the warnings we're relevant. It seems like I am on the right path, but I am not 100% sure...

### Edit 3

I then ran `docker run -p 8080:8080 shot_charts_docker_container` and received the following output:

```
> extensions-api-sdk@0.1.0 start /app
> node node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -p 8765

Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8765
  http://172.17.0.2:8765
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

However when I went to visit those URLs, neither one seemed to work.

### Edit 4

Here's what I receive from running `docker image ls`:

```
> docker image ls
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
shot_charts_docker_container   latest              fd2ef4b32da5        7 minutes ago       1.17GB
node                           12                  d834cbcf2402        8 days ago          916MB
hello-world                    latest              fce289e99eb9        14 months ago       1.84kB
```

and from `docker container ls`

```
> docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
8d71818baf51        shot_charts_docker_container   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 8081/tcp   stupefied_kalam
```

Comment: Hi @canovice. Did you solve your question? If you have statics assets (js html css, etc) is very simple publish them with apache, nginx, python nodejs, etc. Let me know if Do you need any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the ports that the server (the one inside the Docker container) is listening on and the ports that Docker is trying to expose to the world.

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8765
  http://172.17.0.2:8765
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

This output shows the server as listening on port 8765, but your `docker ls` command shows `0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`, so the wrong ports are mapped!

#### Solution

In your `Dockerfile`, `EXPOSE` the ports that the server is listening on.

```
EXPOSE 8765
```

When running the image, **map** those ports to any port of your choosing

```
docker run -p 8765:8765 shot_charts_docker_container
```

`8765:8765` tells `docker` to map the HOST's port 8765 (the first number) to the CONTAINER's 8765 (the second number, the port we `EXPOSE`).

With most setups, the server should then be available at http://localhost:8765.